# How can I Change the store language after switching the store

Tags: magento2, store-view

I have two store one is English and one is French.

Create a product and category in English and French also, but I am **not able to  create category  or product for french**.

Please help, How can I create content like category,product for french store in french language?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create CSV in Below format :

```
sku     | store_view_code    | attribute_set_code   | name

sample  | fr                 | Default              | sample in franch
```

Add your 1000 products in this format with **store_view_code**  and import products from **System >> Import >> Products**

Comment: for CSV format you can first export CSV for products and then fill product data for all fields you want to add

Comment: ok got  it,  I have one issue also ,I have installed franch language ,  but this is not convert in franch when select franch store, @ and can you help me how can i change add to cart and login , create account  all default thing in  franch

Comment: for default string you need to put each string in `echo __('<string>');` to convert and put that string into your global csv file for franch

Comment: if the answer solved your issue than you can correct it so it can be helpful to others

Answer (score 7):

You can set Locale as per store view.

`Admin >> Store >> Configuration >> Select your store from store drop down on top left corner >> Locale Options >> Set your language for store.`

Answer (score 6):

Admin provide to Add Product as well as category data in different language as per store view.

Here for Product : **Admin >> Products >> Catalog >> Open Product >> Select store view**

[image]

Here for category : **Admin >> Products >> Category >> Select Category >> Select store view**

[image]

> Note : To convert into different language you must need to install language pack into Magento as per store view.

Comment: well I can understand . When you select on German, then you have not able to add category

Comment: When you select german you have blank fileds to fill for same category

Comment: but this is manual process, i have 1000 product in english , and right now i want to change all in German, then i have to create one by one , any other away

Comment: create csv for 1000 products with store id and import it.

Comment: asmile.in/admin_1arzd6
user: sanjay
pass: @softweb1234            can you check this

Comment: I have create sample product in frank languiage then export your products CSV for all products which provide me format for different language as `store_view_code` so you can now use same for rest products

Answer (score 4):

Go to **Admin->Products->Categories** in left side above corner you will find **Store View:** select store and save data for particular store. Please show below image for reference

[image]

Comment: if you category is default for all store , you can not create category or product , with this step ,this step working only if you have , different root category for all store, but in different root category , we will lose store switcher form front end